# figuring out overloaded stream operators and copy assignment in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a linked list class and I have trouble with two things:

1. my copy assignment operator doesn't copy the exact list
2. I have no idea how to do the overloaded output with the linked list, I know how it works in basics, but I'm lost with my linked list.

UPDATE:
why is the copy assignment operator giving me reverse of my list?

```
list& list::operator =(const list &l){
    while (p!=NULL)
       del();
    Node* current=l.p;
    while(current!=NULL){
       insert(current->x); 
       current=current->next;
       }
```

when i have 10--2--NULL
It prints 2--10--NULL

Comment: Your question needs to include any and all code required to answer your question. Please don't post links to off-site code.

Comment: thats because of the ostream operator

Comment: I know, but it indicates that you're giving us code different from what you've been testing... You've been testing, right?

Comment: no, i just commented out the operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your assignment operator you set `p` to `current` which must be a null pointer, or you wouldn't have exited the `while` loop.  `p` should already be set by the previous calls to `insert`.

What happens if the list already has elements when you assign to it?  Do you really want to append, or do you want to remove the existing elements first?

In your `print` member the loop runs until `q` is NULL, then after it's finished you test whether `q` is NULL ... of course it is. So you always print NULL after any list.

In `main` you have this, which destroys the list:

```
l1.~list();
```

So the next line is undefined behaviour, because you access an object that has already been destroyed, then the object goes out of scope again and its destructor runs, which is also undefined behaviour because the object has already been destroyed. You don't need to call a destructor manually, that's the whole point of destructors, they clean up automatically when the object goes out of scope.

**Edit:** Your assignment operator copies the list in reverse because you go through it in order but `insert` puts each element at the start of the copied list, so you copy the first element, then put the second element before it, then put the third before that etc.

To copy the list you need to put the copied elements in the *same* order, i.e. insert each one at the *end* not the beginning.

Comment: but i call the destroyer at the end

Comment: See my edit.  And I don't know what "destroyer" is, but your object's destructor gets called twice, that's a very serious bug.  Do not call the destructor, let it get called automatically at the end of the scope.

Comment: "destroyer" and destructor same stuff... and when is the destructor called first?

Comment: and how can i reverse back to the original list

Comment: The destructor is called first when you say `l1.~list();` ... don't do that!  I already told you how to get the order right, put the new elements at the end instead of inserting them at the beginning.

Comment: Your `insert` function puts a new element at the beginning of the list.  If you copy the list [1,2,3] you do `insert(1)`, giving [1], then you do `insert(2)`, giving [2,1], then you do `insert(3)`, giving [3,2,1]